# Including commented Class declaration in implementation file

Tags: c++, documentation, comments, code-readability

Everyone knows the advantages of a more readable code. So in order to make my code more readable what i do normally is include the  commented class declaration in the implementation file of that class.
This way i need not have to browse through various include directories to go to the definition.
So, Is this a good practice or just over-documentation?
If there is some standard technique, plz let me know.
**EDIT:**
Is there a way to migrate to class declaration from implementation in Vim ?
Except opening it in new buffer.

Thanks

Comment: Bad Idea: Most good editors allow you to switch from the declaration to the definition in a couple of keystrokes. Check tags file for vim and emacs and check the options on your fovorite GUI IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually counter-productive, because now you have to change **three** locations instead of two when modifying class declaration, and one of these locations won't be checked by compiler to catch any mismatches.

Also, in large and quickly-evolving projects comments always get obsolete, so they cannot be trusted.

All modern IDEs can help to access class declaration from class implementation in a number of ways, all of which are more convenient than scrolling to the top of file and then back.

As an alternative, consider using an auto-documentation tool such as [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/). Doxygen can be told to include entire class declarations in the documentation -- with syntax highlighting, line numbers and links to the source files. You can include a doxygen pass in your build process and always have an up-to-date code reference.

Answer (score 3):

**This breaks the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle** : you have to maintain the comments when you change the declaration.

And it will not help a lot read your code.

As they say (from memory) : "If the code and the comments tell different stories, they're certainly both wrong."

What will help is :

- **make sure your class declaration in the header is well documented and/or pretty clear about the class usage** : that's where most of the users of the classes will look first because that's the "manual" of your class (be it comments or explicit functions);
- **write those comments in a way telling your intention, not what it will do exactly** : the intention is what it should do, not what it does (if it's buggy) -- that way you give clues to other people (or yourself later) to fix bugs in your implementation because they can understand what you tried to do;
- **don't report your header comments in your definition file** (cpp) because it will be redondant!
- **write comments in the definition code where you need to tell the intention and where what you do might not be obvious**;
- **if possible, replace comments in implementation code by real code (function or class)** : you can often encapsulate a code block in a function with an explicit name or the result of an operation in a variable with an explicit name -- programmers will more thrust executed code than unclear comments....

Comment: C++ breaks the DRY principle by requiring the split header / source... sniff

Comment: I don't think so : declaration and definition are clearly different informations (that complete each other). The problem is that to identify something for it's declaration and it's definition, you have to retype at least it's declaration. If there was a way to simply use the name used in the declaration it would look less like a DRY break.

Answer (score 2):

This does not help a lot, because when class definition is bigger than one screen, your colleagues will have to scroll up to get to the declaration.
Modern IDEs are very good in locating the declaration so IMHO this is useless.

The only thing which really matters sometimes is that you put the access identifier 
in the comment when you define the function. This really saves time for someone trying to understand the code.

Something like this is enough:

```
//private
void Car::ReplaceDriver(const std::string & NewDriver)
{

}
```

Comment: ohh yes.. i see your point.. even that many editors offer segment folding, so long comment may seem to be useless and confusing at first sight

Comment: Yep, if your editor offers segment folding, it usually also offers locating the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider it over-documentation and have never seen it elsewhere.  When modifying the class the comments will be out of sync quickly (or looking there you are never sure).

Not sure what environment you use, but when looking for a declaration, I normally use a function of the editor (on Mac Xcode and Windows VisualStudio you can right-click something and then jump to it's definition or declaration).